# Absolute positioning layout with bootstrap2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, positioning

I am able to make a two column layout that extends the full length of a container-fluid using absolute positioning.  What I want to do is be able to create a two column layout where each column fills up the entire container using row-fluids.  However, when I try this my row fluid only take up the height of the text in the div.

Here is an example of what I want to be able to do but where the row-fluid extends to the bottom of the container.

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="row-fluid">
           <div class="span2">

            </div>
            <div class="span10">

            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

But the only way I can get it to work is using absolute positioning which I found an example of on this site.

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="sidebar">
        </div>
        <div id="content">
    </div>
```

using this css:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
background-color:darkcyan;
}

.container-fluid {
    min-height: 100%;
    padding:0px;
}

#sidebar, #content {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}

#sidebar {
    left: 0;
    width: 15em;
    background-color: bisque;
}

#content {
    left: 18em;
    right:0;
    background-color:bisque;
}
```

Here is a link to a fiddle that works using absolute positioning, but I want to get a similar effect using bootstrap row-fluids and spans. http://jsfiddle.net/PrFeA/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percentage values in CSS need an explicit value in the parent element, otherwise they won't work, that means that to get your `.span` columns to fill the `.container-fluid` height, you need to set an explicit height value to both `.container-fluid` and `.row-fluid`:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color:darkcyan;
}
.container-fluid {
    height: 100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.row-fluid{
    height: 100%;
}
/*Styles for the span columns*/
.row-fluid > div{
    background: bisque;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Check out the **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/PrFeA/1/show/)**